# GHCJS: How do I import a high order javascript function using FFI?

Tags: javascript, haskell, reactive-extensions-js, rxjs, ghcjs

How do I import in GHCJS a Javascript function like the following ?

```
xs.subscribe(function(x) { console.log(x) })
```

I tried various combinations of the following without success:

```
data Observable_
data Disposable_

type Observable a = JSRef Observable_
type Disposable = JSRef ()

foreign import javascript unsafe "$1.subscribe($2)"
  rx_subscribe :: Observable a -> JSRef (a -> IO()) -> IO Disposable
```

Any help is appreciated, and links to documentation of the GHCJS FFI.

Thanks

Comment: Have you read http://weblog.luite.com/wordpress/?p=14 ?

Comment: I did, but I haven't found an example on how to import a javascript function that takes a Haskell lambda as argument and transforms it into a JavaScript function like the one above.

Comment: is this for a Famo.us codebase by any chance?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to the guys on the GHCJS IRC Channel I got the answer:

```
foreign import javascript safe "$1.subscribe($2)"
  rx_subscribe :: Observable a -> JSFun (a -> IO()) -> IO Disposable

subscribe :: FromJSRef a => (a -> IO()) -> Observable a -> IO Disposable
subscribe f xs = syncCallback1 True True f' >>= rx_subscribe xs
                 where f' x = fromJSRef x >>= f . fromJust
```

Thank You